# How to block magnet links using Squid WEB proxy

Tags: squid, block, torrent

I have Squid filtering all my WEB traffic running on port 80, I managed to block all torrent links using this ACL `acl mediapr urlpath_regex \.torrent$` but I am not able to block magnet links.

Comment: more info about magnet links here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot block magnet links using proxy, since they are direct links to the Bittorrent network itself, and they have nothing to do with web.

You would have to implement Bittorrent filtering in your firewall in order to block those.

Comment: hmm, maybe then there is a way to filter (parse) all website source before sending it to client and replace ":magnet" with something else?

Comment: Content adaptation is possible with Squid: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation . However, one needs to be really careful when implementing Content adaptation like that, so that it doesn't cause problems with other web content...